# Resolve Wordpress plugins conflict settings tab

Tags: wordpress, plugins, settings

Has anyone had the problem of enabling one wordpress plugin would take over the settings tab of another plugin? 
I'm referring to the plugins:  TrainUp and Membership

Whenever I enable Trainup, the membership would disappear, luckily the page is still accessible via the same URL. but this is a bit frustrating

[image]

Thanks

Comment: They both plugin must given the same position just search `add_menu_page` in both plugin files & change position of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Menu conflict can be reduced by using decimal instead of integer values for position, e.g. 63.3 instead of 63

More details about add_menu_page function can be found here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page

Comment: That did the trick, Thanks Avin.I've also contacted the plugin author.